# Upgrade ACB to MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

We did some comparisons on MVVM libraries (MVVM Light, Caliburn.Micro, Prism etc) and we will choose MMVM Light because it seems to offer: a huge userbase, lots of functionality and updates plus a gentle learning curve.

Previous event handling was done with Attached Command Behaviors (ACB): [Marlon Grech's site](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)

What would be our best approach in upgrading? Do we need to delete all previous ground work, or is there a simple upgrade path?

Regards,

Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you want is the **EventToCommand** behavior out of the MVVM Light framework. its almost the same like ACB.